# Group rows content by id

Tags: r, reshape

Suppose I have a number of checks for analysis looking like this:

```
Check_ID Category Items Cost
  000      Sugar     1     1
  001      Milk      1    10
  001      Butter    2    20
  001      Bread     1     5
```

and I want to make it look the following without manually setting the number of rows:

```
Check_ID Category.1 Items Cost Category.2 Items Cost Category.3 Items Cost
  000      Sugar      1     1
  001      Milk       1    10    Butter     2     20   Bread      1     5
```

I need to understand which products are usually taken together. Maybe there's an alternative solution, but I'm pretty stuck.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this may need some clarification before it's solved, for instance, what form is your data in, a data frame or a list etc? what format is each of these columns? You can always post some code to help others reproduce your work. this may help http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `reshape` after creating a unique "time" variable. That's easy to do with `getanID` from my "splitstackshape" package:

```
library(splitstackshape)
getanID(mydf, "Check_ID")
#    Check_ID Category Items Cost .id
# 1:        0    Sugar     1    1   1
# 2:        1     Milk     1   10   1
# 3:        1   Butter     2   20   2
# 4:        1    Bread     1    5   3
reshape(getanID(mydf, "Check_ID"), direction = "wide", idvar = "Check_ID", timevar = ".id")
#    Check_ID Category.1 Items.1 Cost.1 Category.2 Items.2 Cost.2 Category.3 Items.3 Cost.3
# 1:        0      Sugar       1      1         NA      NA     NA         NA      NA     NA
# 2:        1       Milk       1     10     Butter       2     20      Bread       1      5
```

Comment: Very nice, though can't you avoid using `reshape` here?

Comment: I don't know, maybe something vectorized such as `dcast` maybe? I don't have time to do tests right now, sorry :)

Comment: @DavidArenburg, not until Arun pushes version 1.9.8 of "data.table". You can't do that unless you first `melt`, which might not be good if you have different types of data in different measure columns.

Comment: @AnandaMahto though, the output seems not to be a data frame, am I correct?

Comment: @AntonBelyanin, the output is both a data.frame and a data.table.